# Streamfunction of stokeselet

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

Given an incompressible vector field $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$, it holds that $b= \nabla \times \Phi$ for some vector field $\Phi$. I would be interested in the simple situation where $b$ is the velocity induced by a point force in a Stokes flow (also called "stokeslet"). I'd need a precise representation of $\Phi$, but incredibly I cannot manage to find any formulas online for the streamfunction (i.e. for $\Phi$). Do you maybe have some suggestions or references? Or even better, do you have the formula for $\Phi$?